# Webpack + Express + EJS: Error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I'm writing an express web app with webpack, typescript and ejs. When hitting one of the routes that's supposed to serve a .ejs file I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "."
   at webpackMissingModule (/Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:20669:74)
   at new View (/Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:20669:152)
   at EventEmitter.render (/Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:18776:12)
   at ServerResponse.render (/Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:20479:7)
   at /Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:25508:7
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:4524:5)
   at next (/Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:4743:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:4724:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:4524:5)
   at /Users/max/Development/test/express-webpack/dist/server.js:4054:22
```

Here's the code:

### package.json:

```
{
  "name": "express-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "debug": "^2.6.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.5",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.6",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.3"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    target: "node",
    output: {
        filename: "server.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'src/views', to: 'views' }
        ])
    ],

    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

### src/index.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "./views");
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('index'); // <-- error originates here AFAIK
});
app.listen(8000);
```

### views/index.ejs

```
hello world
```

### Reproduction steps:

- Run `webpack` to build the project
- Start the server with `node dist/server.js`
- Visit `http://localhost:8000`
- Expect to see the contents of index.ejs, instead get above stack trace

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I digged into webpack generated code and I found it seems there is a bug with [context parse evaluation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#parser-evaluation) of webpack. There is a simple expression that express uses to require selected view engine, but it is failing to resolve that.

To overcome this issue, in your index you can write

```
const ejs = require("ejs").__express;
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");   
app.engine('ejs', ejs);// <-- this does the trick
```

But if you want a definitive solution, open an issue on webpack repo.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Issue created here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4009

Comment: Wow... I've been hunting down this issue for hours now. This did the trick. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

Adding on Cleiton's answer, you now have to have a callback function in while calling app.engine(string, callback)

```
app.set('views', 'src/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express); //<-- this
```

Comment: This is the actual answer! Thanks heaps!

Comment: I am using netlify-lambda and serverless. Setting it like `app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express)` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I belive your issue it has to do with the fact that your bundled file (dist/server.js)
does not have access to your dependencies, express, template engine etc. In order to
sort that out you can configure webpack to avoid bundling the dependencies 
(due to the fact your app is running from server/node side):

```js
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    target: "node",
    output: {
        filename: "server.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"a
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'src/views', to: 'views' }
        ])
    ],

    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    }
};

// Node module dependencies should not be bundled
config.externals = fs.readdirSync("node_modules")
.reduce(function(acc, mod) {
   if (mod === ".bin") {
   return acc
 }

   acc[mod] = "commonjs " + mod
   return acc
}
```

You might also need to override node global config, using the node option config
to make the views folder accessible from your bundled file, more details: 
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx

That config could also help you https://gist.github.com/madx/53853c3d7b527744917f

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.

Comment: Happy to update my answer with more details and context with what i believe the issue is. Sorry if it is not clear enough and i really appreciate your feedback @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: When you update it, post back here to let me know, and I will plus 1 you :)

Comment: done, however i don't know how to remove my other duplicated answer, there was a refresh problem and it has been posted twice. thank you again @GrumpyCrouton.